# How to create an app to restart/reboot android phone using a button in android studio?

Tags: android, restart, reboot

i want to restart my android phone by using a simple application which contain a button. By clicking the button my phone should be restart. I am using android studio latest version.

Answer (score 1):

You probably wont be able to do this. You can restart the phone by using

```
final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
pm.reboot(null);
```

However, as far as I am aware, this is only available to system applications.

Comment: You'll probably find if you check logcat that the crash is due to not having permission to reboot the phone